# Does MPI blocking call (MPI_Send/Recv) have a time limit?

Tags: mpi, blocking

I am submitting MPI jobs on my university cluster. With larger programs I have noticed that during one of my final communication routines, my program crashes with almost no helpful error message.

```
mpirun noticed that process rank 0 with PID 5466 on node red0005 exited on signal 9 (Killed).
```

The only thing helpful in all of that is that rank 0 caused the problem. Since this final communication routine works as follows (where `<-->` means `MPI_Send/Recv`)

```
   rank 0    rank 1    rank 2    rank 3 ...    rank n
     |        <-->      <-->      <-->          <-->
     |
     |
     |
     |
     |
     |
     |
     V
  ----------------------MPI_Barrier()------------------
```

My guess is that rank 0 hits `MPI_Barrier()` waits for a very long period (570-1200 s) then causes an exception. Alternatively, the computers might run out of memory. When my local machine runs out of memory, I get a very detailed out of memory warning, but I have no idea what is going on on the remote machine. Any ideas what this might mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its most definitely not a timeout. MPI routines do not have such exceptions. If your cluster has a different MPI library (or the same MPI library compiled with a different compiler) or startup mechanism, give that a try. Its probably an issue with the library (or a bug in your program).

Comment: Then in that case it might be a memory issue.

Comment: Quite possible, try compiling with symbols, run with ulimit -c unlimited and see if it dumps core.